# How to declare a list of constants for bigquery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

just playing around with setting parameters in BigQuery.

I know this works:

```
DECLARE X STRING;
SET X = 'APPLE'

SELECT *
FROM DATASET
WHERE name = X
```

Now I want to set a list of parameters to be used as a reference, like:

```
DECLARE X ???;
SET X = {'APPLE','BANANA','CHERRY'}

SELECT *
FROM DATASET
WHERE name in UNNEST(X)
```

What should I use in '???'
Using string obviously gave an

*Query error: Cannot coerce expression*

error, but I am unsure what category to use. Array doesn't seem to work either? :(

Thanks for the help.
CN

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want an array of strings.  I would write this as:

```
DECLARE X array<string>;
SET X = array['APPLE', 'BANANA', 'CHERRY'];
```